# Facebook Share connect js is very slow

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using this snippet:

```
function loadFacebook()
{
    var app_id = $('meta[property="fb:app_id"]').attr("content");
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: '//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js',
        timeout: 2000,
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        success:
            function() {
                FB.init({ appId: app_id, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
            }
        });
    var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
    $('#facebook-sharing').append('<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="'+pathname+'" data-width="140" data-type="button_count"></div>');
}
```

It seems that doesn't cache for nothing, and page loading is very, very slow. Other sites that I saw seem don't have this problem.

I know there are other similar question but nothing seems to solve my trouble. Thank you.

Comment: I know there's not much difference, but can you try and use the getScript() method? Details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/)

Comment: uhm..... about 1 second to loading instead of ~ 2 ;) Btw a solution, for the moment ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that worked. I'll post it as an Answer here for future references. You can mark it as accepted if you're not able to find any other alternate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `getScript()` method. The `getScript()` method is asynchronous, so you’ll pass an anonymous callback function in which you can do your SDK initialization code as usual.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    });     
    $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
  });
});
```

Source: [Facebook SDK for JavaScript with jQuery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery/).